# Create PHP timestamp to insert into mysql databse

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

How do I create this using PHP, for the current timestamp, ready to insert into a mysql database timestamp field:

```
2015-06-27 12:58:10
```

I want to insert a created_timestamp field basically...

I don't want to use the database's "on update current timestamp" feature because I want this to be a permanent fixed record.

Comment: Have you done any research or put any effort into your question?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes but I'm terrible with timestamps and such functions.

Comment: @AmyNeville But I think you know how to use google. So: `PHP date` <- That's it first php.net manual page and you got it all there.

Comment: @Rizier123 if I knew I was looking for the date function then yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'll accept in 9mins